# Does the value function of a quadratic program stay convex when adding constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, sensitivity-analysis

I am interested in the value function of a quadratic program of the form
$$
v(y)=\min_x \frac{1}{2} x^\top Q(y) x,
$$
subject to a linear equality constraint
$$
E(y)x=d(y),
$$
and a linear inequality constraint
$$
A x \preceq b,
$$
where $\preceq$ denotes component-wise inequalities.

Notice that $Q$, $E$ and $d$ all depend on a parameter $y\in{\Bbb R}^m_{\geq 0}$. $Q(y)$ is positive definite for all $y$. Importantly, $A$ and $b$ do not depend on $y$.

For the particular problem I am interested in, I know $Q$, $E$, $d$, $A$ and $b$ but they are a bit complicated and I'm hoping that their specific structure is not important here.

**I would like to show that $v$ is convex.** Given my specific problem, I know that $v$ is convex if we remove the inequality constraint $A x \preceq b$. In that case the problem is simple and I can solve for $v$.

My question is: if $v$ is convex without the inequality constraint, does $v$ remain convex when we add the inequality constraint? Recall that this inequality constraint does not depend on $y$.

Notes:

1. If that helps, in my specific problem $Q$ and $E$ are homogenous in the sense that $Q(\lambda y)=\lambda Q(y)$ and $E(\lambda y)=\lambda E(y)$ for any $\lambda\in{\Bbb R}$, and $d(y)=y-c$ where $c\in{\Bbb R}^m_{\geq 0}$. $E$ is also linear in $y$.
2. I tried to compute $v$ using the dual approach but this seems intractable.
3. I have looked at a few special cases and cannot find a counterexample.

**Value function without inequality constraints**

Without the inequality constraint, the [solution to this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) is given by

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
Q & E'\\
E & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
\lambda
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
d
\end{array}\right]
$$
which can be [inverted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) as
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
Q & E'\\
E & 0
\end{array}\right]^{-1}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
Q^{-1}-Q^{-1}E'\left(EQ^{-1}E'\right)^{-1}EQ^{-1} & Q^{-1}E'\left(EQ^{-1}E'\right)^{-1}\\
\left(EQ^{-1}E'\right)^{-1}EQ^{-1} & -\left(EQ^{-1}E'\right)^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Since $Q$ is positive definite it is invertible. Suppose that $EQ^{-1}E'$ is also invertible. Then
$$
x=Q^{-1}E'\left(EQ^{-1}E'\right)^{-1}d
$$
and the objective function at the optimum is
$$
v(y)=d'\left(\left(EQ^{-1}E'\right)^{-1}\right)d
$$

**My particular problem**

In my particular problem $x\in{\Bbb R}_{\geq 0}^{n^2}$ and $y\in{\Bbb R}_{\geq 0}^{n}$. The function $E$ and $d$ are
$$
E(y)=y'\otimes I_n,
$$
and,
$$
d(y)=y-c,
$$
where $c$ is a $n\times 1$ column vector such that $0<c_i<1$. The matrix $Q(y)$ is given by
$$
Q=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
y_{1}F_{1} &  & 0\\
 & \ddots\\
0 &  & y_{n}F_{n}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $F_i$ is an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix.

Doing the matrix algebra, and using the expression for $v$ above, we find
$$
v(y)=\left(y-c\right)'\left(\sum_{i}y_{i}F_{i}^{-1}\right)^{-1}\left(y-c\right)
$$
A proof of convexity for this function can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739698/convexity-of-bf-x-mapsto-bf-x-bf-a-top-left-sum-i-x-i-bf-a).

Comment: Is $E$ additive (which would make it linear) or just homogeneous? A key issue is whether, given feasible $\hat{y}$ and $\tilde{y}$ and $\lambda\in (0,1),$ the constraint $E\left(\lambda \hat{y} + (1-\lambda)\tilde{y}\right)x=d\left(\lambda \hat{y} + (1-\lambda)\tilde{y}\right)$ has a solution in the polyhedron of feasible $x$ values.

Comment: @prubin Yes both $E$ and $d$ are additive.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742218/does-the-value-function-of-a-quadratic-program-stay-convex-when-adding-constrain

Comment: You said $y$ has dimension $m$ and $c$ has dimension $n$. Is one of those a typo?

Comment: Yes! $c$ has dimension $m$. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I've also cross-posted to math overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451487/does-the-value-function-of-a-quadratic-program-stay-convex-when-adding-constrain

Comment: You state that you can prove convexity if you remove the inequality constraints. For me, the inequality constraints are harmless and the equality constraints are the stumbling block. It might be helpful to see your argument for convexity with the equality constraints retained and the inequality constraints removed. (A link to a write-up would be fine.)

Comment: I have added how I prove the convexity without the inequality constraint, as well as more details about my specific problem.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451487/does-the-value-function-of-a-quadratic-program-stay-convex-when-adding-constrain/ for an answer to this question by @fedja. It turns out that $v$ is not convex in general, but there are some restrictions we can impose on $Q$, $E$, $d$, $A$ and $b$ such that it is.